# Solve a wave-equation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

We have the following problem

\begin{cases}
u_{tt}=u_{xx}\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi,t)=0\\
u(x,0)=\cos x\\
u_t(x,0)=-\cos x
\end{cases}

The correct  approach should be:

We have homogeneous Neumann conditions on x, so we can make the ansatz:

$$u(x,t)=\cos nx \ u(t)$$

Insert in the PDE and get the ODE:

$$u_{tt}+n^2u=0$$

This gives the eigenvalue $\lambda:=\pm in$

This gives the solution on $t$:

$$u(t)=A\cos nt + B\sin nt$$

Use Initial conditions and obtain:

$A=\cos x$ and  $B=-\frac{\cos x}{n}$

So this should be the correct basis to form the general solution:

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos n x \bigg(\cos nt-\frac{sin nt}{n}\bigg)\cos x$$

But somehow, this is not correct.

Where was the error made?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just plug in $u(t)$ to get $A$ and $B$. You write the full solution:$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n\cos nx\cos nt+B_n\cos nx\sin nt$$
Now plugging in $t=0$ you get $$u(x,0)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n\cos nx=\cos x$$
That means $A_{-1}+A_1=1$ and all other $A_n$ are zero. Then calculate $u_t(x,t)$:
$$u_t(x,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty -nA_n\cos nx\sin nt+nB_n\cos nx\cos nt$$
Plug in $t=0$ and you get $$u_t(x,0)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty nB_n\cos nx=-\cos x$$
The only terms you are allowed to keep are $n=\pm 1$, so $$-B_{-1}+B_1=-1$$

Comment: negative $n$'s are not independent, so you can just take positve ones and you get $A_1=1$ and $B_1=-1$, so $u(x,t) = \cos(x) (\cos(t)-\sin(t))$.

Comment: @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh Correct. $\cos x=\cos (-x)$

Comment: Thanks Andrei! This I will study in detail tomorrow

Comment: @Andrei did you make a typo on $A_{-1}+A_1=1$? I though you would write $A_{-1}=1$ and $A_1=1$. Why did you sum them? Having only two $A_n's$ and both are the same, then $A_{-1}=A_1=1\longrightarrow A_n=1$. And for the $B_n$, since we have $B_{-1}=-1$ and $B_1=1$, then this gives that $B_n=(-1)^n$?

Comment: This gave me $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty=\cos nx\cos nt+(−1)^n\cos nx\sin nt  $ Which I checked, and it is correct.

Comment: In your expression you keep only $n=1$, so $u(x,t)=\cos x \cos t-\cos x\sin t$